# Solaris: information on sparc hardware

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, sun, ultrasparc

I'm having 2 solaris machines to manage, So i want to write my own scripts for getting various information. I'm able to get most of the information but not able to retrieve following:

- Chassis type
- Mother Board S/N
- OS Language

I have no physical access to the machine. I'hv already tried `dmi_cmd` but it just got stuck at connecting. I'm not able to find `sneep` package. locale does not provide language information. Even if i try to set it, the command exits with error saying unable to set locale.

`smbios` would not work hence its a sparc machine.

Comment: You can only get the S/N if you've installed sneep and set the serial manually. There's no other way to get it other than a physical check.

Comment: @James can you please share a location where i can download sneep i couldn't find this package?

Comment: Log in to My Oracle Support and look for the Service Tools Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Little rusty on sparc/solaris, but these might help ...

- Chassis type : As far as I remember one of the `uname` switches will give you a model, e.g. v240.  If you just run `uname -a` it should be in there somewhere.
- S/N : try `prtconf -v` or `lsconf`
- `echo $LOCALE` ?

Comment: uname does not tells whether its a desktop/laptop/server
prtconf does not revels S/N in my case 
echo $LOCALE ? does not return anything i tried without ? also

Comment: However i was thinking of that chassis can be derived from the model name given by uname -i and use some look ups to decide laptop/desktop/server that would be requiring look up table it will not be consistent if the machine changes

Comment: `echo $LOCALE` should be `echo $LANG` or `/usr/bin/locale` - but that reports the locale/language settings you use, which aren't necessarily the system defaults (users can choose their own language).   `locale -a` lists all the locales installed on the system.

Comment: @alanc I want something like "locale -ck LC_IDENTIFICATION" in RHEL it specifies english etc

Answer (score 0):

The command prtdiag will give you as much HW info as I have seen on Solaris machines look at /etc/default/init for default language settings

Comment: It does not gives chassis type (laptop/Desktop/server) and mother board S/N

Comment: Thats the best I have found on Solaris if it isn't contained there as far as HW info you will be pressed to find it from software :(

Comment: There is no parameter in that file for language. however on RHEL it can be retrieved by locale -ck LC_IDENTIFICATION

Comment: Any way thankx trent for your time